# Development with css-grids and well... strange things happen

Tags: css, css-grid

I am building a skeleton for a site that is the making.
I guess the question I got is probably a noob question but still I have to ask it and hopefully, it will help someone else.

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#maingrid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr repeat(2, 2fr) 0.5fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". first first ."
    "second second second second"
    "third third third third"
    "fourth fourth fourth fourth"
    "fifth fifth fifth fifth";
}

.firstrow {
    grid-area: 1 / span 4;
    justify-self: center;
    background-color: #0080bf;
}

.firstcontent {
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 60vw;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

.firsttext {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    text-align: center;
}

.firstnav {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    text-align: right;
}

.secondtrow {
    grid-area: second;
}

.thirdrow {
    grid-area: third;
    background-color: mediumorchid;
}

.fourthrow {
    grid-area: fourth;
}

.fifthrow {
    grid-area: fifth;
    background-color: #0080bf;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>grid</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="maingrid">
    <div class="firstrow">
        <div class="firstcontent">
            <div class="firsttext">Test</div>
            <div class="firstnav">tesT</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondrow"></div>
    <div class="thirdrow"></div>
    <div class="fourthrow"></div>
    <div class="fifthrow"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

On the codepen site, I have what is done so far, and yes it is quite an advanced grid build I need to do.

So what is the question then?
Well the background-color on the first line, I need it to span the whole row not just behind the content.

Antoher fun thing is that the same code downt show any color on the fifth row in my local enviroment using FF70.

Comment: a typo here: `secondtrow` --> `secondrow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to the code and it seems that it works now. The following code might help you, I changed the `.firstcontent` and `.firstrow`.

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#maingrid {
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr repeat(2, 2fr) 0.5fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". first first ."
    "second second second second"
    "third third third third"
    "fourth fourth fourth fourth"
    "fifth fifth fifth fifth";
}

.firstrow {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: 1 / span 4;
    justify-items: center;
    background-color: #0080bf;
}

.firstcontent {
    display: grid;
    width: 60vw;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.firsttext {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    text-align: center;
}

.firstnav {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    text-align: right;
}

.secondrow {
    grid-area: second;
}

.thirdrow {
    grid-area: third;
    background-color: mediumorchid;
}

.fourthrow {
    grid-area: fourth;
}

.fifthrow {
    grid-area: fifth;
    background-color: #0080bf;
}
```

I'm not able to recreate the other issue for the fifth row.